# 'page-break-always: always' not working in itextsharp

Tags: itext

When i use

```
'page-break-always: always'
```

style in table. The parser throws following exception:

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "",
"ExceptionType": "iTextSharp.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException",
"StackTrace": "   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorker.StartElement(String tag, IDictionary`2 attr, String ns)\r\n   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.StartElement()\r\n   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.state.TagEncounteredState.Process(Char character)\r\n   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.ParseWithReader(TextReader reader)\r\n   at HtmlToPDFAPi_ITextSharp.Controllers.PdfController.SavePDFFromHTML() in C:\\Users\\pshankhareman.DOMAIN\\documents\\visual studio 2015\\Projects\\HtmlToPDF\\HtmlToPDFAPi_ITextSharp\\Controllers\\PdfController.cs:line 84\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
"InnerException": {
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline cries, it cannot find it's own context.",
"ExceptionType": "iTextSharp.tool.xml.PipelineException",
"StackTrace": "   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.AbstractPipeline.GetLocalContext(IWorkerContext context)\r\n   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.css.CssResolverPipeline.Open(IWorkerContext context, Tag t, ProcessObject po)\r\n   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorker.StartElement(String tag, IDictionary`2 attr, String ns)",
"InnerException": {
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Exception of type 'iTextSharp.tool.xml.NoCustomContextException' was thrown.",
  "ExceptionType": "iTextSharp.tool.xml.NoCustomContextException",
  "StackTrace": "   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.ctx.WorkerContextImpl.Get(String klass)\r\n   at iTextSharp.tool.xml.pipeline.AbstractPipeline.GetLocalContext(IWorkerContext context)"
}
```

}

I have tried to add the style to div element also. It does not seem to work. It throws the same error.

The exception is thrown only when the writer has 'OnEndPage' event attached to it. It works fine if i remove the event, but it need that to add footers to the page.

Is there anything I am doing wrong? Is there any better way i can force the div to go to a new page?

**Update:**

I have realized that this happens only when i try to parse html footer in the event listener.

I am doing this:

```
footer=XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(footerHTML.Replace("pageNum", document.PageNumber.ToString()).Replace("updateDate", date), footerCss);
```

Once it goes back to the parsing method, it fails throwing the error described above.

Comment: Hi! Are you the person who opened this issue on GitHub? https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/issues/12 If so, could you update your StackOverflow question with the full stack trace you posted in the GitHub issue?

Comment: Sure. I have added now.